# SwiftUI window size for document based MacOs App

Tags: swiftui

I am moving my app from SwiftUI xCode 11 to the new Document Based App lifecycle format in xCode 12. I have not been able to figure out how to set the window size. In Xcode 11 I had

```
window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1200, height: 800),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
```

How do I achieve  the same effect with no AppDelegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (as window by default has .fullSizeContentView)

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
          .frame(width: 1200, height: 800)    // << here !!
          .frame(minWidth: 800, maxWidth: .infinity, 
               minHeight: 600, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, but it leaves the window fixed size and it cannot be resized, which was possible with the old approach. I have tried using "idealSize" with the same numbers but I end up with a smaller window which I always have to resize. If I try (maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) I also end up with a smaller window. In all cases the app comes up minimized. I assume the "styleMask" contains the missing pieces?

Comment: OK, that helps!!! With the double .frame statement the window is also resizable. Still comes up minimized for some reason. So if anyone has a solution for that I would be happy to hear but I mark the question as answered for now. Thanks!

Comment: This does not work for Catalyst unfortunately. Any ideas?

Comment: This works in Bug Sur 11.2.3 for setting the window's size, but if I resize the window, it shifts the child views around, rather than resizing them. That is, the List view on the left gets pushed off the left edge of the window's bounds. Seems like a bug, which I've reported.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on macOS 13. It just makes the content inside my window the specified size, and the window is still the size it's been defaulting to (larger).

Answer (score 3):

In macOS 13.0.1, this works:

```swift
    var
    body: some Scene
    {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: MyDocument())  //  Or WindowGroup
        { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
        }
        .defaultSize(width: 200, height: 400)     //  <-- Set your default size here.
    }
```

Note that app state restoration might confuse matters, but creating a new document (or deleting app state) should create a new window with the specified default.

Comment: I worked on this for hours before finding this answer. This is the only thing that worked for me. I added `.defaultSize` to my WindowGroup and the default size is now correct.

Answer (score 0):

I used the trick of swapping out the minimum size. It's not elegant, but it solves the problem.

```
struct ContentView: View
{
    @ObservedObject var document: MyDocument

    @State var minSize:CGSize = {
        // Set your preferred initial size here
        guard let screen = NSScreen.main?.frame.size
        else { return CGSize(width: 800, height: 600) }
        return CGSize(width: screen.width * 0.75, height: screen.height * 0.75)
    }()
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Text("Content")
        }
        .frame(minWidth: minSize.width, minHeight: minSize.height)
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                await Task.sleep(500_000_000)
                // Set your real min size here
                minSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 400)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope the next SwiftUI will have a normal way.